# irqbalance using just 1 numa nodes

Tags: networking

i have a problem, I installed a network card intel i740 4x10Gbit and bonded mode 4 all 4 interfaces. but it loads just 1cpu :( 
in ircbalance --debug
i can see that irqbalance see 2 numa_nodes, and parameter (-1) use all available, but it loads just 1 numa node, and 2nd numa node is free and not loading.
at /proc/interrupts also i can see that using just 1 cpu with 16cores, the 2nd cpu is free.

please, i do not know what to do, i tried smp_affinity manually, but i would like to understand whats wrong with irqbalance and how push it to use 2 numa-node

Answer (score 1):

By default irqbalance uses the `/proc/irq/*/affinity_hint` to decide on the target CPUs for a given interrupt, so even if you set `numa_node=-1` the `affinity_hint` (set by the kernel based on which numa node the interface is actually connected) may trump that.

You may try adding `OPTIONS="--hintpolicy=ignore"` to `/etc/default/irqbalance`.

I'm assuming you are already using `--policyscript=` option for setting `numa_node=-1`.